# Change working directory

Tags: zip

I'm trying to compress a directory at

```
/home/cyrus/sql
```

And I wanted to change the working directory when zipping the folder:

```
/ $ zip -b /home/cyrus sql.zip /home/cyrus/sql
```

But when I check the zip file:

```
/ $ unzip -l sql.zip

Archive:  sql.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2013-05-30 10:59   home/cyrus/sql/
  1776642  2013-05-23 10:22   home/cyrus/sql/wordpress.sql
---------                     -------
  1776642                     2 files
```

The root folder should have been `sql`. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `man zip`:

> ```
> -b path
>
>  --temp-path path
> ```
>
> Use the specified path for the temporary zip archive. For example:
>
> ```
> zip -b /tmp stuff *
> ```
>
> will put the temporary zip archive in the directory /tmp, copying over stuff.zip to the current directory when done. This option is useful when updating an existing archive and the file system containing this old archive does not have enough space to hold both old and new archives at the same time. It may also be useful when streaming in some cases to avoid the need for data descriptors. Note that using this option may require zip take additional time to copy the archive file when done to the destination file system.

By default `zip` stores the full path relative to the current directory. If you want your zipfile to have your `sql` directory as the root, you'll need to run the command from the `/home/cyrus` directory.

Comment: `zip` is strange to store full path in archive.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to `zip` the content of a given directory and store the `zip` file in the current directory, you can write it:

```
(cd /some/dir && zip -r - dir-there) > file.zip
```

Or if like me you're more used to the `tar` command line interface, with libarchive's `bsdtar`:

```
bsdtar -cvf file.zip --format=zip -C /some/dir dir-there
```

Answer (score 7):

It may be easier to symlink the folder you are trying to zip to the current directory. That way you can stay where you are.

```
ln -s /path/to/whatever .
zip -r myzip whatever
```

Them rm the symlink if you desire.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: definitively the most useful one at least

Answer (score 5):

`-b` specifies where `zip` should put temporary files, not that it should change directory somewhere. From `man zip`:

```
 -b path
      Use the specified path for the temporary  zip  archive.
```

Try this:

```
cd /home/cyrus && zip sql.zip sql
```

Comment: Or `cd /home/cyrus && zip /sql.zip sql` if you want the zip file created in the root.

Answer (score 3):

not sure if I understand this right but -b will not change the root folder. It will put the temporary zip archive in the directory /home/cryus, copying over sql.zip to the current directory when done.  This option is only useful when updating an existing archive, and  the  file  system containing  this  old archive does not have enough space to hold both old and new archives at the same time.

try to use:

-j     Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store
              directory names. By default, zip will store the full  path  (relative
              to the current path).

Comment: `-j` might not be right; I would assume the OP wants to keep relative paths, not remove all paths.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Stephane's answer:

```
(cd /home/cyrus; zip -r sql.zip sql;)
```

The result:

1. you have a sql.zip in /home/cyrus/
2. sql.zip contains sql/ directory and all its content
3. you initial PWD doesn't change

Comment: How is this better?